# Excel pivot table with macro to consolidate values based on field name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I have a table with two relevant columns "**src**" and "**on hand**".  In the **src** column I have two types of entries for each row that I want to treat in different ways when creating the pivot table.

> 1. For any entry with a value in the src column with a string of length > 2, I want to create a new row in the pivot table with that
>      value.
> 2. For the "**on hand**" field, I want to get the "on hand" value of the last entry under that row with a src value where the length of the
>      field name is 2;

For example, where the original table reads (Name of Product = src):

```
-------------------------
|Name of Product|on Hand|
-------------------------
|foo            |(1.000)|
-------------------------
|xx             |0.000  |
-------------------------
|xx             |(1.000)|
-------------------------
|xx             |7.000  |
-------------------------
|bar            |0.000  |
-------------------------
|xx             |(1.000)|
-------------------------
|xx             |2.000  |
-------------------------
```

The pivot table becomes:

```
-------------------------
|Name of Product|on Hand|
-------------------------
|foo            |7.000  |
-------------------------
|bar            |2.000  |
-------------------------
```

Unfortunately I have no sense of orientation on this and am unsure where to start.  Is there a general approach to this sort of problem?

Comment: create a new flag column containing the length of the src column and add it as a  row filter

Comment: Do you have a link on creating flag columns?  I'm way behind the learning curve on this one.

Comment: create a column callled flags =len(A1) and drag it to all of the values in the a column and add this to the pivot table rows and then you will get different hierarchy in the rows spliting based on the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two helper columns. Enter the formulas detailed below in columns `C` and `D` and copy them down. You then run your pivot table on Columns `C` and `D`.

See the screenshot:

[image]

**Category** is based on this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,A2,IF(LEN(A2)=2,C1,A2))
```

Which says:

- if the row is 2 just take the product (because its the first row we can't look at the 'above' value)
- else, if the product has length of 2 take the value above
- else, take the product - meaning `bar` becomes the new value because length >3

**Closing** is based on this formula:

```
=IF(C2<>C3,B2,0)
```

Which says:

- if the category below is the same then we're not at the closing balance
- else, the category below is new therefore we've reached the closing balance